# How do I extract number from a String in Java?

Tags: java, string, substring

```
String classs = "java1110======$500.50";
```

and I want to extract 500.50 from the String value. What should I do?

I tried replace() but it gives me 111050050.

Comment: where are your `replace()` codes?

Comment: `String#subString` and `Sting#lastIndexOf` would probably help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
class.substring(class.lastIndexOf("$") + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the  ASCII range of numbers to set up the condition that whenever the ASCII value of a particular character comes up in between you put it in a character array,or any string variable,it's all on your discretion.
Hope this helps